# Create file in Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to know how is it possible to create custom file located in extension root directory using JavaScript or Chrome API.

Extension root directory looks like:

- popup.html
- popup.js
- manifest.json
- icon.png

And I would like to create JSON file called test in that root directory.

So after that it should look like:

- popup.html
- popup.js
- manifest.json
- icon.png
- **test.json**

**test.json** should contain:

```
{
  "data": "123456789"
}
```

It is not duplicate, because that post is for File Dialog and I need to save it at fixed location and in extension folder. And as I said I want to create it, not download it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Comment: @SheshankS. No because it is for File Dialog, but I need to save it at fixed location and in extension folder. And as I said I want to create it, not download it.

Comment: Oh I see @tomsk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The extension directory cannot be used for storage -- its contents are not synchronized across machines, and the directory is replaced entirely when the extension is upgraded.

If you need to store data in a Chrome extension, use [the `chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage).